# Trying to install Git on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, git

I'm trying to install Git on Ubuntu 14.04  (Trusty Tahr)...
When I typed

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

it said:

```
E: Unable to locate package git
```

So I ran:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E1DD270288B4E6030699E45FA1715D88E1DF1F24
sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/git.list"

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
       Recommends: patch but it is not installable
       Recommends: rsync but it is not installable
       Recommends: ssh-client but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix it, and what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the following the `git-all` package certainly exists on 14.04 and does *not* require a PPA:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ apt-cache policy git-all
git-all:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
     1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     1:1.9.1-1 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
andrew@corinth:~$
```

It is in the 'Universe' section of the Ubuntu Repositories so make sure you have this activated by following the trail:

```
Dash --> Software & Updates --> Ubuntu Software --> Community maintained....
```

See this screenshot where the mouse cursor indicates the appropriate Repository:

[image]

After activating 'Universe' and allowing the Repository index to reload, rid yourself of the PPA and then simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

And all should be well...